# Laravel 5 named routes error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I defined this named route in my routes.php,

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@home'
]);
```

then I have this in my PagesController.php

```
public function home() {
    return 'Welcome home!';
}
```

My question is why http://localhost:8000/home produces this error?

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Comment: Refer this documentation, it will explain the routing concept well [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't created a `route` for the url `/home`. You only created the `/` route.

To further explain your problem, you just named your route with `home`. That means you can link to `{{url()->route('home')}}` in your view to go to the URL `/` which will be your home page. You can also access this route from any controller using `url()->route('home')`.

If you want to access the page `/home`, you need to create a route for this.

eg:

```
Route::get('/home', ['as'=>'NameUrRoute', 'uses'=>'PagesController@SamplePage']);
```

`'as'=>'home'` just indicates the name for the route. Not the `URI`.

Answer (score 2):

The route `name` is `home` so you can access it from a controller, or view using `URL::route('home')`. But the actual address in the URL is `localhost:8000/`